# Multiple values for custom fields in Activities?

Tags: custom-fields, activities, developer

Anyone has seen any custom implementation/extension of custom group multiple values for Activities?

Since we are using Activities for many different scenarios, many times the requirement of having multiple values' custom groups for Activities pops out (which now a day is only available for Contacts)

Any lead/tip will be appreciated

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: An Org is using Activities to process Product Requests from the members. 

Activity Type: Product Request
Custom Group: Product Request details
Custom Fields:
- product: select (prod1, prod2, ..)
- quantity: int

this group needs to be repetitive, because a request can contain multiple products and quantities, and is treated as a single request

Comment: From my researches a few month ago I would say there is no way atm – if you can't add an activity per product/quantity.

Comment: Hi @luciano_s how could you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

If someone interested I'm developing a custom extension to extend multi-value custom groups for Activities.
Still work in progress: https://github.com/ixiam/com.ixiam.modules.multivalueactivity

Comment: Hello, has there been any update on this?