# Multi-value fields in profile

Tags: profile

Can someone explain to me step by step, please, how to create the multivalue fields illustrated in the User Guide under the title Multi-value fields in profiles? (It shows work experience list, but I wish to use it for something else. However I do not understand even how to create this work experience list!)
Thanks!
Mike Somorjay

Comment: We avoid multi-value fields where we can by adding them as standard fields to an Activity type and hence being able to record the data multiple times - just a thought for others reading this if they hit obstacles

Answer (score 1):

Multi-value fields can only be created on the Contact entity, which may be what's confusing.  Here are the steps (with screenshots):

- **Administer menu » Customize Data and Screens » Custom Fields**.
- Click **Add Set of Custom Fields**.
- Set *Used For* to "Contacts".
- Check the box *Does this Custom Field Set allow multiple records?*

[image: Create custom field set]
[image: Select multi-value checkbox]

Comment: Note that there is [an extension under development](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20247/multiple-values-for-custom-fields-in-activities) to allow multi-value custom fields on activities as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a duplicate of [Edit Multi-Value / Multi-Record Fields in Profiles](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/9557/edit-multi-value-multi-record-fields-in-profiles?rq=1)

It's only possible to add multiple-value field in profile in edit mode (not in create mode), i.e. the contact must already exists in the database and the link should be https://example.org/civicrm/profile/edit?gid=XX&reset=1&id=YY with XX=`profile ID` and YY=`contact ID`.

You might want to add a checksum if you don't want your user to log in.

**EDIT 2018-10-09**: checksum doesn't work because the link to the edit popup doesn't get the checksum

**For reference**, the documentation that is mentioned in the question is :

> https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/#multi-value-fields-in-profiles
>
> [image]